# Send File to HTTPS URL using CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, upload

I am attempting to send a file to an Https URL with this code:

```
$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$target_path); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'file='.$file_to_upload); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
echo " Server response: ".$result; 
echo " Curl Error: ".$error;
```

But for some reason I'm getting this response:

```
Curl Error: Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

Any advice would help thanks!

UPDATE: When I take out CURLOPT_UPLOAD, I get a response from the target server but it says that there was no file in the payload

Comment: You have confirmed `$target_path` is a valid and readable file?

Comment: I have yes, its octal is 775, owner apache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing a rather strange argument to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Try something more like:

```
<?
$postfields = array('file' => '@' . $target_path);
// ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
?>
```

Also, you probably want `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to be `true`, otherwise $result won't get the output, it'll instead be sent directly to the buffer/browser.

[This example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) from php.net might be of use as well:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Once you hit a certain reputation level you can see the cumulative ups and downs that result in the overall score. I didn't know *who* downvoted, just that someone did. What are you wanting me to edit, by the way? Did I misstate something? I haven't seen any criticism.

Comment: How to use this for multiple files?

Answer (score 5):

On top of coreward's answer:

According to [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php), starting from php 5.5 you need to use `curl_file_create($path)` instead of `"@$path"`.

Tested: it does work.

With the `@` way no file gets uploaded.