# how to upload file using curl with PHP

Tags: php, curl, upload

How can I upload a file, either by using cURL or anything else, in PHP?

In other words, the user sees a file upload button on a form, the form gets posted to my PHO script, then my PHP script needs to re-post it to another script (eg on another server).

I have this code to receive the file and upload it:

```
echo"".$_FILES['userfile']."";
$uploaddir = './';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if ( isset($_FILES["userfile"]) ) {
    echo '<p><font color="#00FF00" size="7">Uploaded</font></p>';
    if (move_uploaded_file
($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile))
echo $uploadfile;
    else echo '<p><font color="#FF0000" size="7">Failed</font></p>';
}
```

How can I send the file to the receiver server?

Comment: not with "ftp" , i want to send the file with curl in $_FILES['userfile']

Comment: Uhm...what now? Where do you want to send it? What's your target system?

Comment: to php file (source in question) - target system is linux

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Use:

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
  $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
} else { // 
  $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
}
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=> $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

You can also refer:

http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/

**Important hint for PHP 5.5+:**

Now we should use https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload but if you still want to use this deprecated approach then you need to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);`

Comment: thanks but how to upload it in different name like the file name is x.php and i want to upload it with z.php name

Comment: In the about example "sample" is the name. you can access the data using $_FILES['sample']
so you can pass x.php and retrieve using $_FILES['x']

Comment: Maybe, is a better way use the built-in feature from curl: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-file-create.php. Of course, you can use the way of POSTFIELDS and fill the value prepending with `@`.

Anyway, the asnwer is copied from a custom usage of curl from a blog. The correct answer is say that the `@` char defines it as a file, not a var. $post will contain `@filename.jpg` by example.

Comment: @erm3nda  That's PHP 5.5+ only.

Comment: @fiXedd im currently using php 5.6, and using `curl_file_create` is required (the sollution provided by karthik is not working). So the code should be upgraded to something like this: `if  function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
 $cFile = curl_file_create($dest);
} else {
 $cFile = '@' . realpath($dest);
}`

Comment: Now we should use https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload but if you still want to use this deprecated approach then you need to set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);

Comment: What is `extra_info => 123456` used for?

Comment: this solution stopped working in php 5.6, the solution is in adding file as: new CURLFile(realpath($fileName));

Comment: @MarekRoj You make my day

Comment: CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD is not supported for php7

Comment: `but if you still want to use this deprecated approach then you need to set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);` - this won't work as of PHP 7.0

Comment: This code though, I can't get file content

Comment: The RFC should be the answer for it. Thanks for providing clue here.

Comment: Will this work for uploading a CSV file?

Answer (score 9):

For those using php >= 5.5, [`CURLFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) can be used:

```php
$curlFile = new \CURLFile('test.txt', 'text/plain', 'test.txt');

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => $curlFile,
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    echo 'upload - FAILED' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

From php 8.1, the file can only reside in memory if desired using [`CURLStringFile`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlstringfile.php):

```php
$txt_curlfile = new \CURLStringFile('test content', 'test.txt', 'text/plain');

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => $txt_curlfile
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    echo 'upload - FAILED' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Reference: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/CURLStringFile

Answer (score 0):

```php
$filePath = 'your_file_full_path';
$image = fopen($filePath, "rb");
$ch = curl_init();

// If authorization is needed, then use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER //
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer your_token'
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'upload_url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePath));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```