# how to upload files on different hosts?

Tags: php, apache, file, upload, host

i have a website that users can upload video clips on it.

i want to use different servers. one for hosting just my files and one for my php files and ...!
is it possible to do this?

i want to send it via $_POST method.

for example my upload page is on host 1 :

```
host 1/upload.php"

host 2/videos/file1.mp4
```

and i want to allow users upload video clips some where in host 2 :

```
 host 2/videos/file1.mp4
```

how can i do this?

### tnx

is it possible to put my upload.php page on a host 2 and include it in a page within host 1?
i want to upload files directly on second server and don't use bandwich of first server
???

Comment: You can try FTP http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php or CURL http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php - See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/15200632/ for a CURL solution.

Comment: tnx . if i upload files to host 1 and then move to host 2 it will use my bandwith?!  i want to use bandwich of second host

Comment: That I couldn't say for sure. You'll need to track your logs.

Comment: is it possible to uoload my upload.php script on host 2 and then include it in a page in host 1 (for example index.php). does it work? and is it secure way?!