# PHP Send local file by cURL

Tags: php, curl, upload, restful-architecture

Im trying to send a local file by client curl app. I found some examples to do that with files from a form. In my case, I have no form, but a local file.

```
$fileName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/www/images/test.pdf";

if(!file_exists($fileName)) {
       $out['status'] = 'error';
       $out['message'] = 'File not found.';
       exit(json_encode($out));
}
$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@'.$fileName);

$cURL = curl_init("http://myapi/upload-images");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($cURL);
$error = curl_error($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

die($response);
```

With this, I have no erros, but in server the $_POST and $_SERVER arrays is empty.

I tried otherwise, this time creating a Curl file before send:

```
// Mime type of file 
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);

$cFile = new CURLFile($fileName, $finfo, "file");

//var_dump($cFile);
//CURLFile Object
//(
//   [name] => C:/.../test.pdf
//   [mime] => application/pdf
//   [postname] => file
// )

$cURL = curl_init("http://myapi/upload-images");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
array(
     'file' => $cFile
));

$response = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

die($response);
```

Same response. $_FILES is empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php

Comment: Thanks for your answer @StrawHat. In my first case i tried that, by adding realpath(). Same response, $_FILES is empty in server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the reason of issue. The array with file data must have filedata and filename keys.

We can pass '@' before file name with full path but this is deprecated.

```
$data = array( "filedata" => '@'.$fileName, "filename" => basename($fileName));
```

In this case I added a Curl object:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);

$cFile = new CURLFile($fileName, $finfo, basename($fileName));

$data = array( "filedata" => $cFile, "filename" => $cFile->postname);
```

The full code is:

```
$fileName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/www/images/test.pdf";
$fileSize = filesize($fileName);

if(!file_exists($fileName)) {
    $out['status'] = 'error';
    $out['message'] = 'File not found.';
    exit(json_encode($out));
}

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName);

$cFile = new CURLFile($fileName, $finfo, basename($fileName));
$data = array( "filedata" => $cFile, "filename" => $cFile->postname);

$cURL = curl_init("http://myapi/upload-images")
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// This is not mandatory, but is a good practice.
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    )
);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);

$response = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);


die($response);
```