# How to use in cURL a posted file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, curl

I'm coding a kind of **php proxy**, for internar services.

I'm doing a pretty simple use of curl like this:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
//set timeout to infinit 
set_time_limit(0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);

if ( strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' ) {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST) );
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, getallheaders());

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

//Request
list( $header, $contents ) = preg_split( '/([\r\n][\r\n])\\1/', curl_exec( $ch ), 2 );
$status = curl_getinfo( $ch );  
curl_close( $ch );
```

**I need to include** also in that curl exec the **incoming file**. I don't know the filename, just the form input name.

### Question

1) How could I include the content of $_FILES in that CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?
2) Do I need to specify if it's a binary file ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple example of how to send files via cURL. You don't need to mention that it's a binary file.

```
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filename = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

$data = array(
    'uploaded_file' => $tmp.';filename='.$filename,
);

$ch = curl_init();   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
// set other cURL options here.

curl_exec($ch);
```

Now, on the other side you can receive the details in `$_FILES`.

receiver.php (assuming this is what cURL calls to to).

```
var_dump($_FILES)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that is not working. I'm receiving the tmp file path. This is the raw request: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updoaded_file"
/tmp/phphga6Mb;filename=Jellyfish.jpg.  $_FILES is empty

Comment: I've found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228367/php-send-local-file-by-curl?lq=1