# Converting a Curl command into PHP Curl code (file transfer & custom command)

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to convert the following Curl command:

```
curl --digest --user "username:password" --verbose --url "http://127.0.0.1/ws?graph-uri=http://localhost/dataset/import/" -X POST -T /data/datasets/foo.n3
```

Here is the code that appears to be ok, but that doesn't work:

```
$args = array();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1/ws?graph-uri=http://localhost/dataset/import/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
$args['graph-uri'] = curl_file_create('/data/datasets/foo.n3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It seems that the file is actually **not** uploaded with the PHP code, but everywhere I look the usage of `curl_file_create()` seems good.

Comment: What is $args before you add the cURLFile Object?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Just edited the question to make it explicit. Basically: an empty array.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the code that handles this request.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php), substituting graph-uri for file_contents.  Also, you are setting "graph-uri" as both GET and POST params, which could collide, and the graph-uri GET param is not URL encoded, which could behave differently in the shell vs. PHP.  So you might try the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1/ws?graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdataset%2Fimport%2F
```