# PHP Curl Put multipart

Tags: php, curl

I need help converting following CURL command to PHP.

```
curl -X PUT -F file=@myfile.zip -F file_type=binary \
    "https://example.com/rest/api/path"
```

Using PHP 5.6 so `'file'=>'@'.$filename` is not an option.

Comment: please explain your question more. what error are you getting?

Comment: look this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php#answer-15200804

Comment: You probably want multipart POST, not PUT...

Comment: @DanielStenberg The api doesn't work with POST. Only PUT.

Comment: @mmm The problem is that `file:'@'.` syntax is not working on php 5.5+.

Comment: @Mojtaba: PUT with multipart formpost? That is *highly* unusual.

Comment: @DanielStenberg I've tried `-X POST` on terminal, it doesn't work. Only work if you do `PUT`. The API document says the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to convert your request in to PHP:

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('https://example.com/rest/api/path');

// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('myfile.zip') .
      ';type='     . $_FILES['file']['type']
));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

**UPDATE FOR 5.6**

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('https://example.com/rest/api/path');

// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, new CurlFile('myfile.zip', $_FILES['file']['type'], 'myfile.zip'));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Comment: `'file' => '@' . realpath('myfile.zip')` won't work on php 5.5+. Says you should use `CurlFile` which doesn't work either

Comment: If CurlFile do not work, make sure you enabled `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`

Comment: You are using `CURLOPT_POST` but I need `PUT`