# What is the cURL -T option in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post to a file service with CDN translating the cli -T option to PHP code, but I don't really know what the equivalent is, or what is the corresponding code that would replicate it. I've seen a options around CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, but that doesn't seem to work in correspondence to other headers.

The exact thing I'm trying to replicate is this:

`curl -XPUT -T "test.png" -v -H "X-Auth-Token:MYTOKEN" -H"Content-Type: text/plain" "https://somecdn.com"`

I think it's something like this, but I'm unsure:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set up the options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mycdn.com/test.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                "X-Auth-Token: mytoken",
                                                "Content-type: text/plain"
                                            )
                                        );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file" => "@test.txt") );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I'm surprised, I suppose, that -T flag doesn't have a similar curl_setopt.

So the precise question is this:

What is the proper way to replicate cURL CLI `-T "test.png"` in PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using curl with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: so just a file upload with curl ?

Comment: That is correct - I've adjusted my question to better describe what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: "I think it's something like this, but I'm unsure:" so does it work? if not whats the porblem, we are not psychic

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why you have twot variables as $ch and $resource?

Comment: Sorry - that was a copy/paste mistake. I have fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take into consideration as PHP 5.5 uploading file this way (@filename) is deprecated.
Also, PHP 5.5 introduces a new option/flag regarding upload process, called by `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`:

> **TRUE** to disable support for the @ prefix for uploading files in
>   **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**, which means that values starting with @ can be
>   safely passed as fields. [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) may be used for uploads instead.
>   Added in PHP 5.5.0 with **FALSE** as the default value. PHP 5.6.0 changes
>   the default value to TRUE.

So if you've PHP 5.5+ you must set **CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD** (though 5.5 is false by default) to `false`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

Another option is using the [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) class.

**And remember:** Filename MUST be absolute path.