# Convert CURL in to PHP CURL call but getting error of authorization

Tags: php, curl, bearer-token

**I am calling cURL call like below but wanted to convert in to PHP format**

```
curl https://apis.voicebase.com/v2-beta/media \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
--form media=@/home/harshal/Desktop/100Hz_44100Hz_16bit_30sec.wav\
| tee media-post-response.json | jq '.'
```

**Above cURL wanted to convery in to PHP format like below**

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);      
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

**but getting error of authorization but when I pass parameters to cURL like Token & audioUrl it works. but it does not works when pass parameters like above php CURL_OPT**

Comment: What's the value of `$header`?

Comment: header value is $header = "Authorization: Bearer ${token}";

Comment: Have you checked if `$token` in PHP has the same value in shell?

Comment: Yes Token value is right.
also I am passing parameters 
$params = array(
             "media" => $mediaURL,
             "action" => "media-post-response",             
             "format" => "txt"
   );

Comment: Do you know if the server will return authorization error if any of the parameters is invalid? I think you used wrong way to post a file, but usually it happens after the authentication part, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the [php curl official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) , it says:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  
    An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type:   text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')
```

So I think you need change your `$header` to `$header = array("Authorization: Bearer ${token}")`

Comment: Its "Authorization: Bearer {$token}" not "Authorization: Bearer ${token}"