# how to move temp file in a case of just knowing its path?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just can get the temp file path,like D:\XAMPP\tmp\phpE185.tmp...But the $_FILE array is null,because I do a transport from a url to another url.So how to move this temp file?

here is my code:

```
 class UserController extends Controller
{


public function getRank(){

    echo "waht";
}

public function uploadTrans(Request $request){

    $image = $request->image;
    $name = $request->name;

    $image = urlencode($image);
    $curlPost = "name=$name&image=$image";

    $uploadApi = "http://mdx.ittun.com/authprac/public/upload";
    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$uploadApi);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$curlPost);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;

}
public function upload (Request $request){


    $fileTempName = $request->image;
    print_r($fileTempName);

 //   here I just can get the temp file path..$_FILES array is null
    }
}
```

Comment: No code makes it very hard to help

Comment: sorry , I've edit.@dbmitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function for this purpose.

Since you've tagged your question with [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), see their [docs regarding uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files):

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath);
```

Comment: I can not get file by $request->file(''),it's null

Comment: You aren't sending the file in the CURL request. Why don't you just call the upload method directly without reuploading the file?

Comment: I just  wanna try how to move file like this..So how could I do it?

Comment: How can I reupload in the curl request?

Comment: yeah,of cource..i've try fopen(),fread() and other php function,but they all require file,not just the path..

Comment: `fopen()` has nothing to do with uploading a file with cURL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php