# Curl works on command line but not in PHP.

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a .csv file to an API. The API documentation says to post it like this:

```
   curl --user username:password
    --request POST
    --data-binary @yourfile.csv
    https://api.example.com/api
```

This works perfectly.

in PHP I have it like this:

```
    $data = array('myfile' => 'myfile.csv');
    $curl = curl_init('https://api.example.com/api');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username" . ":" . "password");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $result;
```

The results do equal what the API documentation says is the correct response (and is the same response as when using the command line) however it does not actually upload the contents of the file.

is my PHP structure correct? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using curl with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php with PHP 5.5+

Comment: I tried the curl file object approach but its still not working.

Comment: All you are doing is sending the filename not the contents of the file