# Unable to upload file using curl with php

Tags: php, curl, upload

I was stuck with the same problem but it looked like the `'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'` or adding `@` did not resolve the issue.

References:
[how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: can you post your full code

Comment: I have found the solution but it was not easy to find given that I am a newbie to php. Sharing my learning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change here is we have to use the function `CurlFile` in place of `@`.

For multiple filesuse multiple tags:

```
$data['<Filetag1>'] = new CurlFile('<Filename1>');
$data['<Filetag2>'] = new CurlFile('<Filename2>');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```