# Post image via CURL PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, post

So I'm trying to mime the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarygLmTBM5HATvn9tpA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

p1bieoilebde1ra71v4tm2rlb3h.png
------WebKitFormBoundarygLmTBM5HATvn9tpA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="watch.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarygLmTBM5HATvn9tpA--
```

My code looks like this

```
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../images/watch.png"));

$to_post = array ('file' => $cfile);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $to_post);
```

And it's not working, any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php

Comment: there must be more php code than this? There is no `curl_exec` for instance

Comment: try `$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../images/watch.png",'image/png','watch.jpg'));`  ?