# Sending a file via PHP CURL to remote server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a file using PHP's CURL functions.

```
$postdata = curl_file_create(realpath($filename), 'text/csv', $filename);
```

and then

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$cinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$cerror = curl_error($ch);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($cinfo);
var_dump($cerror);
curl_close($ch);
```

This only dumps `bool(false)`, so I'm not getting far with the debugging. Am I POSTing the filename as a string rather than the file contents? The php script and the file to be send are in the same directory. Do I need to specify the path in a certain format?

**Update**:
I added `curl_error($ch)` and figured out that the problem is a connection timeout. When running the script from my local machine it seems to be working, at least I get a `200 OK` reply. Could my webhost somehow be blocking the connection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php

Comment: @colburton Thanks, I already tried that but it doesn't give me a different result :(