# Walmart API item feed error INVALID_REQUEST_CONTENT

Tags: php, curl, multipartform-data, walmart-api

I have been having the hardest time getting an item uploaded to walmart..
I get the following error
**

> _ INVALID_REQUEST_CONTENT.GMP_GATEWAY_APImoreThanOneFeedRequest content is invalid.ERRORDATA

**
I believe it may have something to do with the payload/data  however i tryed many differnt formats an am unable to get past this generic error.

my test url is

> http://sandbox.gottires.com/api/walmart/senddata-walmart33.php

I would very much appreciate if someone can help..   this is driving me crazy
below is my code:

```
 $URL = 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds?feedType=item';
    $RequestMethod = 'POST';//Request method type i.e GET, POST
    $Timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000); //Current system timestamp
    $WalmartConsumerID = '66543541tedyhyde3t53.524';

    function _GetWalmartAuthSignature($URL, $RequestMethod, $Timestamp) {
      $WalmartPrivateKey = 'dgjsdhsehsethsethsehsetjrdjrj';//Your Walmart Private Key;

      $WalmartConsumerID = 'djdrtudrturdtu';//Your Walmart Comsumer Id;
      // CONSTRUCT THE AUTH DATA WE WANT TO SIGN
      $AuthData = $WalmartConsumerID."\n";
      $AuthData .= $URL."\n";
      $AuthData .= $RequestMethod."\n";
      $AuthData .= $Timestamp."\n";
      // GET AN OPENSSL USABLE PRIVATE KEY FROMM THE WARMART SUPPLIED SECRET
      $Pem = _ConvertPkcs8ToPem(base64_decode($WalmartPrivateKey));
      $PrivateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($Pem);
      // SIGN THE DATA. USE sha256 HASH
      $Hash = defined("OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256") ? OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 : "sha256";
      if (!openssl_sign($AuthData, $Signature, $PrivateKey, $Hash))
      { // IF ERROR RETURN NULL
      var_dump(base64_encode($Signature));
      echo "</br> Failed  signiture </br>";
        return null;
      }
      //ENCODE THE SIGNATURE AND RETURN
      return base64_encode($Signature);
    }
    //echo _GetWalmartAuthSignature($URL, $RequestMethod, $Timestamp);



    function _ConvertPkcs8ToPem($der){
      static $BEGIN_MARKER = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
      static $END_MARKER = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
      $key = base64_encode($der);
      $pem = $BEGIN_MARKER . "\n";
      $pem .= chunk_split($key, 64, "\n");
      $pem .= $END_MARKER . "\n";
      return $pem;
    }

    function auth($url, $RequestMethod,$Timestamp,$WalmartConsumerID){
        $qos = uniqid();
       // $headers[] = 'POST /v3/feeds?feedType=item HTTP/1.1';
        $headers[] = 'WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace';
        $headers[]= 'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: '.$qos;
        $headers[]= 'WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP: '.$Timestamp;
        $headers[]= 'WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE: '._GetWalmartAuthSignature($url, $RequestMethod, $Timestamp);
        $headers[]= 'WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE: 0rduyrdturdrt0e005832524d';
        $headers[]= 'WM_CONSUMER.ID: '.$WalmartConsumerID;
        $headers[]= 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=12345'; 
        $headers[]= 'Accept: application/xml';
        // $headers[]= 'Host: https://marketplace.walmartapis.com';
        //$headers[]= 'Host: marketplace.walmartapis.com';
        //var_dump($headers);
        return $headers;
    }

    $val = file_get_contents('http://ak-websolutions.com/dev/walmart/product.xml');

    $eol = "\r\n";
    $data = '';

    $mime_boundary="12345";

     $data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;

    $data .= ' ' . $eol . $eol;



     $data .= '<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8""?>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<MPItemFeed xmlns=”http://walmart.com/” xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance” xsi:schemaLocation=”http://walmart.com/ MPItem.xsd „">' . $eol;
    $data .= '<MPItemFeedHeader>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<version>3.1</version>' . $eol;
    //$data .= '<mart>WALMART_US</mart>' . $eol;
    //$data .= '<locale>en_US</locale>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</MPItemFeedHeader>' . $eol;


    $data .= '<MPItem>' . $eol;

    $data .= '<sku>UHP-8224-JH</sku>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<processMode>CREATE</processMode>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<productIdentifiers>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<productIdentifier>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<productIdType>UPC</productIdType>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<productId>849849004721</productId>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</productIdentifier>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</productIdentifiers>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<MPProduct>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<productName>295  30 R 22 103Y  ANTARES MAJORIS M5  30 K MILES </productName>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<ProductIdUpdate>Yes</ProductIdUpdate>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<SkuUpdate>No</SkuUpdate>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<category>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<Vehicle>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<Tires>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<shortDescription>295  30 R 22 103Y  ANTARES MAJORIS M5  30 K MILES</shortDescription>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<brand>ANTARES</brand>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<mainImageUrl>https://www.stuff4crafts.com/media/catalog/product/4/3/437764.jpg</mainImageUrl>' . $eol;
    $data .= '<tireSize>2953022</tireSize>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</Vehicle>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</Tires>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</category>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</MPProduct>' . $eol;
    $data .= '</MPItem>' . $eol;

    $data .= '</MPItemFeed>' . $eol;

    $data .= "--" . $mime_boundary . "--" . $eol . $eol; // finish with two eol's!!

    $ch = curl_init( $URL );
      //echo $val;  
        $ch = curl_init(); // Initialize the curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);  // set the opton for curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);// set the option to transfer output from script to curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, auth($URL,$RequestMethod,$Timestamp,$WalmartConsumerID));
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
        if($data!="")
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true); 
           // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $val);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }else{
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $val);
            echo "Empty";
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);


        //die();
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $getinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
        ;
    $responsecode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($responsecode != '200'){
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_PRIVATE));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CONNECTCODE));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL ));
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_UPLOAD));
        //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
        var_dump($data);
            var_dump($getinfo);

        }

        if(curl_error($ch)){
            echo "Curl Error:  " . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        echo '<pre> Error: ';
        print_r($response);
```

Comment: When you get that far, you'll need to swap the `</Vehicle>` and `</Tires>` closing tags so they nest correctly.

Comment: thanks,  but same error  i tryed with test data and same issue..   i just corrected that though..   no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You get that error if it cannot find the attachment or too many attachments. Try looking at this [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)