# PHP upload file using a directory string

Tags: php, curl

I have a string that representing a file path like this: `D:/folder/another_folder/image_name.png`.

I want to send this as a file using PHP curl I've doing this but it doesn't work

```
$ch = curl_init();   
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+  
    $cFile = curl_file_create('D:/folder/another_folder/image_name.png');  
}else{  
    $cFile = '@' . realpath('D:/folder/another_folder/image_name.png');  
} 

$fields['userPhoto'] = $cFile;  
$fields['uploadedfrom'] = 'web';  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://some_url.com');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(  
    'Content-Type: application/json'  
));  
$result = curl_exec($ch);  

curl_close($ch);
```

the issue is I'm getting the file path from a csv file not browsing it
Can anyone help with this and tell me how to send a file through PHP CURL from a string?

Comment: can you specify _"but it doesn't work"_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: the `'Content-Type: application/json'` seems strange to me (for sending a file)

Comment: Did you do _any_ research? I found _many_ posts about this, just searching for "php curl send file" on google

Comment: @Jeff yes it was the problem using that Content-Type, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem here is that you're using json_encode. json_encode cannot encode CURLFile objects. also, JSON is not binary safe, so you can't send PNG files with json (PNG files contain binary data, for example including the FF/255 byte, which is illegal in json. that said, a common workaround is to encode binary data in base64, and send the base64 in json). stop using json, just give CURLOPT_POSTFIELD the array, and curl will encode it in the `multipart/form-data`-format, which is the de-facto standard for uploading files over the http protocol. going that route, you must also get rid of the `Content-Type: application/json` header, and curl will automatically insert `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` for you.