# Uploading File with CURL and Retrieving in Laravel Method

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-request

I'm trying to get data posted using cURL in my endpoint, which is built on Laravel. In my API controller, where I receive data, I am able to receive all the data except my media file. I check for presence of the file using `$request->hasFile('file')` but it returns false. I also try to get the file using `$request->file('file')` but it returns null.

When I use `$request->get('file')`, I get the following response.

> file":{"name":"/Users/name/File/path/public/media/aaaah.wav","mime":null,"postname":null}

Below, I am using `$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";` to convert the recipient from array to string. Can anyone help me understand why the file posted by cURL is not being received in my Laravel method when I use `$request->hasFile('file')` and `$request->file('file')`?

**AppController**

```
public function postCurlData()
{
   $endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api';          
   $apiKey = '****';
   $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $apiKey;
   $dir = '/Users/name/File/path/app/public/media/test.wav'; // full directory of the file
   $curlFile = curl_file_create($dir);

    $data = [
       'recipient' => ['44909090', '44909090'],
       'content' => 'i love to code',
       'file' => $curlFile,          
     ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

My endpoint where I'm receiving data:

**APIController**

```
public function receiveCurlData()   
{   
    $apiKey = $request->get('key');
    if (($apiKey)) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'content' => $request->get('content'),
            'recipient' => $request->get('recipient'),
            'file' => $request->hasFile('file')                 
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
{"status":"success","content":"I love to code","recipient":
["44909090","44909090"],"file":false}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to your question:
[how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php).

You should delete

```
 $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
```

And

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

And also delete the json_encode() replacing it by the plain array

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
$iconImageFile = $request->file('file');
            $iconfilename = $iconImageFile->getClientOriginalName();
            $icontmpFilePath = $iconImageFile->getPathname();
            $iconImageMimeType = $iconImageFile->getClientMimeType();
            $iconimage = new \CURLFile($icontmpFilePath, $iconImageMimeType, $iconfilename);
             
            $payload = [
                'file' => $iconimage
            ];
            
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL , "url");
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST , true);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  , $payload);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER , true);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
            curl_exec($curl);
            echo $result = curl_exec($curl);
```