# How to post $_FILES with PHP curl?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a curl post request with a $_FILES attachment data that was received.

```
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$fields = array('file_contents' => '@' . $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']);

$resource = curl_init();
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($resource));
curl_close($resource);
```

The request is passing to the second server but without the file. I also double checked the $_FILES in the first server and it's ok but on the second server, it's empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: No, Its something different @KateOrlova