# How to upload files with POST form-data in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

The normal `curl` way, works well.

```sh
curl \
  -F "smfile=@test.png" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  https://sm.ms/api/v2/upload
```

But in my PHP version curl, it returns `bool(false)` and `string(0) ""`:

```php
<?php

$url = "https://sm.ms/api/v2/upload";
$headers = array();
array_push($headers, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
array_push($headers, "User-Agent: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

// $fields = array('smfile' => curl_file_create('test.png', 'image/png', 'test.png'));
$fields = array('smfile' => new CURLFile('test.png', 'image/png', 'tset.png'));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

What's wrong with my code? `ヽ(*。>Д<)o゜`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to upload file using curl with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Comment: @CodyKL I tried the `$fields = array('smfile' => "@test.png");` method in that link but got a `Invalid file source` message from the API side. I checked the curl request header by `curl_getinfo`, in which the content_type is "text/html; charset=UTF-8". I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```php
<?php

$url = "https://sm.ms/api/v2/upload";

// I guess the file is in the same directory as this script
$file = __DIR__.'/test.png'; 

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
];

$fields = [
    'smfile' => new CURLFile($file, 'image/png')
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
var_dump(curl_error($ch));

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this simple code to upload files

```
$explode = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = $explode[count($explode) - 1];

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
'uploads/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
echo $result === true ? 'File uploaded successfuly' : 'There are some errors';
}
else
{
echo 'No File uploaded';
}
```

Comment: Your code matches on a file upload via a form, but the TE want to upload a picture from one server to another server over a API via CURL.