# php send a file via sftp to ipv6 host

Tags: php, sftp, ipv6

My script generates a file that I need php to send via sftp to an ipv6 address.

My first attempts are inconclusive using ssh2_connect() and ssh2_auth_password ().
Basically it seems I do not provide a valid $host value.

```
$host = "[XXXX:XXXX:XX:...]"; // ipv6 enclosed in []
$port = 22;
$user = "XXX";
$pass = "XXXXXXX";

$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass)) {
  error_log("valid connection");
} else {
  error_log("failed connection");
}
```

- the error log returns:

PHP Warning: ssh2_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed

PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to [XXXX:XXXX:XX:...] on port 22...

- [Gethostbyname()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.gethostbyname.php) is invoked and fails. It seems to only support ipv4.

Is there another way to go about this ?

Thank you

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't seem to have any relevance to the question. If you've tried ssh2_sftp(), show us that code, and tell us what happened - did you get an error? did the file not get uploaded to the remote host?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I focused my question and provided more relevant code

Comment: I posted this question which was quickly closed so I modified it the next day, but since is has been 5 days and the question is still closed, I took the initiative to ask the question again...

Answer (score 1):

I have not fully resolved this question, but if you come here with a similar need here are my two cents, what I learned in the process.

- orient yourself to using curl.
- you basically need the url not the ipv6 address, for the DNS.
- you can sftp with curl to your desired location with authentication, even if it is a nested folder and authentication happens at root level.

for debug:
it can be useful to check `curl_getinfo()` prior to an after `curl_exec()`
as well as to echo the return transfer.

```
$user = 'XXXX';
$pass = 'XXXX';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://auth_level/nested_directory/nested_further");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo(var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo('<br>');
echo(var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)));
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
```

[Here is a blog post on uploading a file with curl](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-upload-file-curl/)

[here is a useful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php).

Good luck