# Request sent from POSTMAN to flask works but request sent from PHP curl gives 400 error

Tags: php, curl

I have this php code that sends a POST request containing a file:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://****/ocr_api/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFile('/C:/Users/me/Downloads/test.pdf')),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I copied this code from postman under the "code" options, so this should be the equivalent of it and work without issue? But it still doesnt.

`request.files` shows an empty dictionary then doesnt make it further than that line

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def accept_pdf():
    print("HERE", request.files) ## SHOWS UP EMPTY AND STOPS HERE
    pdf = request.files["file"]
    filename = pdf.filename
    print("FILENAME", filename)
```

Any help? Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php
@Amon check the answer of above question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to upload file using curl with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `multipart/form-data` in your call:

```php
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  [...]
  CURLOPT_HEADERS => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"),
  [...]
));
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer, it's still returning the 400 error. On my backend I'm printing off `request.files` and it's returning `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).