# curl and PHP send data and attachment with Gravity Form

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, gravityforms

first I've got a Wordpress Page with Gravity Form.
on my functions.php is a function to send data to an extern page with curl and php.
There is an array with my post field data and everything works great. BUT I want to send my attachments with it. and there is any problem.

in my function looks the curl part like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://playground.europersonal.com/api/public/v1/Bewerbung/Create');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$post = array(
    'bewerbung' => json_encode($data),
    'attachments' => @https://domain.de/file.pdf'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/plain';
$headers[] = 'X-Apikey: xxxxx';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

the attachment are not sending. I don't know how to get one or more files from my gravityform upload to the "attachments" array for my curl upload.

Anyone can help?

Comment: `'attachments' => @https://domain.de/file.pdf'` isn't valid PHP code. I expect you'd have a syntax error, if that's the real code you're using

Comment: That `@filename` syntax for file uploads is deprecated anyway. Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php

Comment: P.S. See https://3v4l.org/Pn4JO for the syntax error. This should be apparent in your environment too. If not, make sure you've enabled PHP error logging, and then check the log file

Comment: mhm, I need to know how I can use the gravityform field to insert it in this section. I get a full url from the field, and if I insert it like this 

`'attachments' => '@https://domain.de/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-facf26974afc340fd413706e7b9a12d54/2023/11/datei.pdf'` 

it will not working. that's my problem.

Comment: ok. Well `@https://domain.de/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-facf26974afc340fd413706e7b9a12d54/2023/11/datei.pdf` isn't a valid URL, for one thing - get rid of the `@`. And does the remote API even accept URLs in this field? We don't know...you didn't give any link to the documentation of that API so we know what you're supposed to send to it, and we have no idea what "not working" actually means in reality either. Do you get a specific error? Unexpected result (if so, state clearly what is is and what you expected instead)? We cannot see your screen or read your mind, remember.

Comment: okay, sorry... I don't know what's wrong, because there is no error. ;-) 

so... the documentation said this curl info for the attachments. the upload field is called "attachments". `-F \'attachments=@file.jpg;type=image/jpeg\'`

my upload field named "input_8" only get the full url as value. So my workflow was to use the value (my full url of the uploaded file) instead of the filename. okay, I understand, that's not the right way, but I don't know how to get this working

Comment: If the file is uploaded onto your PHP server, you could attach it via the local path to it where you saved it on the server. See articles such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php for more detail. And can you please provide a link to the documentation, rather than just quoting little bits of it? Then we can get the full picture.

Comment: Also even if you don't get an error, do you get any response from the remote server (which might contain useful info)? I notice you aren't trying to look at the content of `$result` in your code, for example.

Comment: here you can find the documentation: [link](https://editor.swagger.io) - "Bewerbung" -> bewerbung/create is what I need.
I will read the article and will try - thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right link...it just points to https://editor.swagger.io/ which opens a generic sample document.

Comment: it must be the prosoftrecruiting API and you can import this json (it's up to 99 views and available for 24 hours) [swagger import demo](https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/qs/654350e512a5d3765993c5d1)

Comment: I tried to import that JSON into the swagger editor online but it doesn't work (it says _"Unable to render this definition
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field. Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.x.y (for example, openapi: 3.1.0)."_). Isn't there some ready-made documentation??

Comment: I've got nothing else. sorry.